# Is this the only way to use MERGE in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, oracle10g

I am moving my first step with Sql Server database projects and I was searching for a way to populate reference tables in post deployment scripts without deleting and refilling them each time. After some research I stumbled upon this blog entry:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/02/02/including-data-in-an-sql-server-database-project.aspx

That basically describes the behaviour of the MERGE statement with this example:

```
-- Reference Data for AddressType
MERGE INTO AddressType AS Target
USING (VALUES
  (0, N'Undefined'),
  (1, N'Billing'),
  (2, N'Home'),
  (3, N'Main Office'),
  (4, N'Primary'),
  (5, N'Shipping'),
  (6, N'Archive')
)
AS Source (AddressTypeID, Name)
ON Target.AddressTypeID = Source.AddressTypeID
-- update matched rows
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET Name = Source.Name
-- insert new rows
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (AddressTypeID, Name)
VALUES (AddressTypeID, Name)
-- delete rows that are in the target but not the source
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE
```

Since I work also with Oracle databases I have tried to adapt the previous sample to Oracle 10g syntax and I've produced something like this:

```
-- Reference Data for AddressType
MERGE INTO AddressType AS T
USING (WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 0 AS AddressTypeID, 'Undefined' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION 
  SELECT 1 AS AddressTypeID, 'Billing' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS AddressTypeID, 'Home' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 3 AS AddressTypeID, 'Main Office' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 4 AS AddressTypeID, 'Primary' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 5 AS AddressTypeID, 'Shipping' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 6 AS AddressTypeID, 'Archive'AS Name FROM DUAL
)
SELECT AddressTypeID, Name FROM CTE
)
AS S 
ON T.AddressTypeID = S.AddressTypeID
-- update matched rows
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET T.Name = S.Name
-- insert new rows
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
INSERT (T.AddressTypeID, T.Name)
VALUES (S.AddressTypeID, S.Name)
```

Besides not being perfectly equivalent (no delete for rows not in source) I find the syntax particularly ankward.

There are any syntactic shortcuts available for Oracle SQL?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way. Oracle doesn't support the `values()` row constructor (except for **single row** `insert` statements). This was true for the un-supported version 10 you are using, but is unfortunately still true for Oracle 12. A workaround would be to use regular `insert` statements with error logging enabled https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55104 (but that still doesn't delete obsolete rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any shortcut, the syntax for **MERGE** is what you have with you.

The only thing you could get rid off is the **WITH clause** i.e. CTE in the **USING** clause. You could simply put it as:

```
-- Reference Data for AddressType
MERGE INTO AddressType AS T
USING (
  SELECT 0 AS AddressTypeID, 'Undefined' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION 
  SELECT 1 AS AddressTypeID, 'Billing' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS AddressTypeID, 'Home' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 3 AS AddressTypeID, 'Main Office' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 4 AS AddressTypeID, 'Primary' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 5 AS AddressTypeID, 'Shipping' AS Name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 6 AS AddressTypeID, 'Archive'AS NAME FROM DUAL
      ) AS S 
ON T.AddressTypeID = S.AddressTypeID
-- update matched rows
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET T.Name = S.Name
-- insert new rows
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
INSERT (T.AddressTypeID, T.Name)
VALUES (S.AddressTypeID, S.Name)
```

And, of course, you cannot update the column mentioned in the `ON` clause.